# ¿Cómo comparar por orden los elementos dentro de dos arrays en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos arrays de igual tamaño (4 cadenas de caracteres), uno con valores predefinidos y otro con cuatro valores que introducirá el usuario, y debo compararlas comparando dos condiciones:
en primer lugar, si alguno de los valores introducidos por el usuario está dentro de los valores predefinidos (si los contiene),
en segundo lugar, si estos valores coinciden en el orden en que se encuentran en el array predefinido:

```
arrayPredefinido = ["azul","verde","rojo","amarillo"];
arrayUsuario = ["azul","rojo","blanco","negro"];
```

En este caso debería devolver que contiene 2 valores correctos, pero sólo 1 en la posición adecuada.

¿hay forma de comprobarlo a través de un forEach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que se puede Pablo.

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```js
      function validacion(){
        arrayPredefinido = ["azul","verde","rojo","amarillo"];
        arrayUsuario = ["azul","rojo","blanco","negro"];
        var contCoincidenciaValor = 0;
        var contCoincidenciaOrden = 0;
    
        arrayPredefinido.forEach(function(elementoPredefinido, i) {
          arrayUsuario.forEach(function(elementoUsuario, j) {
             if (elementoPredefinido == elementoUsuario) {
                contCoincidenciaValor++;
                if (i == j) {
                  contCoincidenciaOrden++;
                }
             }
           });              
         });
        console.log("La cantidad de repeticiones es: " + contCoincidenciaValor);
        console.log("La cantidad de repeticiones en el mismo orden es: " +   contCoincidenciaOrden);
    
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="validacion()">Validar</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto! de este modo funciona como esperaba, gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) para atravesar uno de los arrays, pasándole dos parámetros a la función: el primero será el elemento y el segundo el índice. De este modo, puedes comprobar si el elemento corresponde con el mismo elemento en el otro array (el que comparte el mismo índice).

Si coincide, perfecto; si no, puedes usar [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) para comprobar si el elemento existe en cualquier otra posición del array. De ese modo puedes ver cuántos son correctos y cuántos están realmente en la posición adecuada.

Algo como esto:

```js
arrayPredefinido = ["azul","verde","rojo","amarillo"];
arrayUsuario = ["azul","rojo","blanco","negro"];

perfectMatch = []; // aquí guardamos los elementos exactos
almostMatch = [];  // aquí los que están pero no en la misma posición

arrayUsuario.forEach(function(elemento, indice) {
  if (elemento == arrayPredefinido[indice]) {
    perfectMatch.push(elemento); // existe en esa misma posición
  } else if (arrayPredefinido.indexOf(elemento) > -1) {
    almostMatch.push(elemento);  // existe pero en otra posición
  }
});

console.log("Contiene " + (perfectMatch.length + almostMatch.length) + " valores correctos, con " + perfectMatch.length + " en la posición adecuada.");
```

Comment: Hola Álvaro, tu solución me parece correcta, pero tengo una duda: ¿por qué utilizas dos nuevos arrays en los que almacenas las coincidencias? Lo pregunto porque luego usas Array.length para obtener el número, y entiendo que directamente con un contador valdría. (Todo esto suponiendo que te has centrado en la pregunta concreta del usuario, sin dar la posibilidad de utilizar más adelante esos arrays, que tendría sentido entonces).

Comment: @MigHc sí, lo hice por si el usuario luego quería usar esos valores para algo... pero tienes razón, el usuario no indica eso en su pregunta, por lo que realmente podría usar contadores en lugar de arrays y simplificar la solución.

Comment: Esta solución tiene O(n) para el mejor caso y O(n^2) para el peor caso. El resto de solucionares son O(n^2) para el mejor caso.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que mencionas que siempre tendrán la misma longitud estos 2 arreglos, solo debes de iterar sobre uno y comprobar si con ese índice ambos arreglos tienen el mismo valor.

```
const matches = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrayPredefinido.length; i++) {
  if (arrayPredefinido[i] === arrayUsuario[i]) {
    matches.push(i);
  }
}
```

Otra manera de hacerlo puede ser esta:

```
arrayPredefinido.map((val, i) => val === arrayUsuario[i] ? i : -1).filter(i => i !== -1);
```

Comment: Con un único bucle sólo contemplas la posibilidad que los elementos coincidan solamente cuando su índice sea el mismo.

Comment: @MigHc El usuario está pidiendo que coincidan tanto los valores como las posiciones.

Comment: Según mi interpretación, quiere contemplar ambas cosas, y de manera independiente.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```js
arrayPredefinido = ["azul","verde","rojo","amarillo"];
arrayUsuario = ["azul","rojo","blanco","negro"];

var elementosExistentes = 0; // Inicializamos nuestra variable para elementos existentes
var indicesCorrectos = 0; // Inicializamos nuestra variable para posicion correcta
arrayPredefinido.forEach(function(elPredefinido, idxPredefinido){ // Recorremos nuestro arreglo arrayPredefinido
    arrayUsuario.forEach(function(elUsuario, idxUsuario){ // Recorremos nuestro arreglo arrayUsuario
        if (elPredefinido == elUsuario){ // Comparamos nuestro valor tanto del arreglo Predefinido como el del usuario
          elementosExistentes++; // Si existe, sumaremos a la cantidad de elementos existentes 
          if (idxPredefinido == idxUsuario){ // Comparamos nuestro indice tanto del arreglo Predefinido como el del usuario
            indicesCorrectos++; // Si es el mismo, sumaremos a la cantidad de elementos encontrados en la misma posicion
          }
        }
    })
})

console.log("Existen "+elementosExistentes+" elementos coincidentes y "+indicesCorrectos+" en la misma posicion")
```

En uno de los casos va contando la cantidad de elementos que existen entre los arreglos, y en el otro esta verificando si la posición es exactamente la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar el siguiente código en la consola del navegador. Te indica las posiciones que se repiten en ambos arrays y que son correctas ademas de los strings en ambas situaciones.

```
console.warn('Run test...');

var arr_matches,
    arr_predefined_values,
    arr_right,
    arr_user_values,
    i,
    j,
    predefined_value,
    str,
    user_value;


arr_predefined_values = [
    "azul",
    "verde",
    "rojo",
    "amarillo"
];
arr_user_values = [
    "azul",
    "rojo",
    "blanco",
    "negro"
];
/**
 * En ambos grupos:         azul rojo
 * En mismas posiciones:    azul
 */

/**
 * La primera condición debe cumplirse simpre para que pueda
 * cumplirse la segunda, es decir que si no hay un valor en
 * ambos grupos no puede ser que sus posiciones lleguen a
 * ser las mismas considerando el valor como correcto
 *
 */

//Stores the matches positions from array of predefined
//values
arr_matches = [];

//Stores the coincident positions from array of predefined
//values
arr_right   = [];


console.warn( 'Search for results...' );
for ( i = 0; i < arr_predefined_values.length; i++ ) {

    /**
     * Gets each predefined value
     *
     */
    predefined_value = arr_predefined_values[ i ];

    /**
     * Runs over user values
     *
     */
    for ( j = 0; j < arr_user_values.length; j++ ) {

        /**
         * Gets each user value
         *
         */
        user_value = arr_user_values[ j ];


        if ( predefined_value === user_value ) {
            arr_matches.push( i );

            if ( i === j ) {
                arr_right.push( i );
            }
        }
    }
}

//console.log( arr_matches );
//console.log( arr_right );


console.warn( 'Shows the results...' );
if ( arr_matches ) {
    console.log( 'Encontrados valores predefinidos...' );
    str = 'Posiciones: ';
    for ( i = 0; i < arr_matches.length; i++ ) {
        str += arr_matches[ i ] + ' ';
    }

    str += ' / Valores: ';
    for ( i = 0; i < arr_matches.length; i++ ) {
        j = arr_matches[ i ];
        str += arr_predefined_values[ j ] + ' ';
    }
    console.log( str );

    /**
     * Existiendo valores repetidos en ambos grupos puede
     * haber valores correctos
     *
     */
    if ( arr_right ) {
        console.log( 'Encontrados valores correctos...' );
        str = 'Posiciones: ';
        for ( i = 0; i < arr_right.length; i++ ) {
            str += arr_right[ i ] + ' ';
        }

        str += ' / Valores: ';
        for ( i = 0; i < arr_right.length; i++ ) {
            str += arr_predefined_values[ i ] + ' ';
        }
        console.log( str );
    }
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución sería:

```
Run test...
Search for results...
Shows the results...
Encontrados valores predefinidos...
Posiciones: 0 2  / Valores: azul rojo 
Encontrados valores correctos...
Posiciones: 0  / Valores: azul
```